# desperate. prevent npm from removing files upon error

Tags: node.js, npm

I am absolutely desperate for help. I have spend several days and nights trying to figure out what's most likely a trivial problem.

I am installing a big node package which has several dependencies. Some of those dependencies, however, fail due to a problems with their binding.gyp files which I know how to fix. The problem is that npm DELETES the files as soon as the error is detected, instead of leaving them for me to fix. Specifically, upon using the --verbose option I find that npm does "npm verb unbuild" and then "npm verb rmStuff", followed by "npm verb gentlyRm ...", I DO NOT want this to happen, as I have no chance to fix the corresponding binging.gym files and rebuild.

I am running the latest versions of node and npm. To reproduce this error on a Windows 7 box, try: npm install base58-native@0.1.2 --verbose

I am a programmer but I'm relatively new to node. I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing. I have exhausted all avenues and hit dead ends every time. Any assistance would be sincerely appreciated.

Comment: can you provide the actual output?

Comment: ok, here is some output from npm-debug.log: http://www.pastebucket.com/78261

Comment: Manual modification of stuff inside *node_modules* is very bad thing to do - it breaks dependency encapsulation. Your project should be able to install its deps automatically. If you know how to fix the errors I strongly suggest that you submit a pull request with the fix to the package maintainer. Alternatively, you find a way how to fix the issue **before** dependency installation starts.

Answer (score 12):

I'm amazed nobody else has this problem. Anyway, I made it stop deleting the files by using `--ignore-scripts`

Comment: Mad props for answering your own question *and* being the only one on the internet to have found the solution.

Comment: Much obliged for this solution. Saved me today. I could not understand why the node_modules folder was getting deleted after a failed npm install.